# Can I resign with only compensation letter and no offer letter in hand

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, resignation, india, compensation

I have received compensation letter with compensation details from an MNC. i have not received offer letter yet. I have not received any document regarding company rules and joining date. HR has called and informed my joining date orally and is asking me to resign. I asked them to send joining date in e-mail but no response.i only have one job offer in hand. Can I resign without offer letter and only compensation letter? Can they deny sending offer letter tomorrow? They are promising orally that offer letter would be sent in a month

Comment: Where are you?  I want to vote to close this as a company-specific policy question, but it may be legal, as well.  Honestly, the abbreviations and jargon here are impenetrable to me, so I'm inferring this is India?  Please edit this to make it something we can address.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea to resign without a written offer in hand. HR can deny tomorrow. Their interest is in getting a person as soon as possible, so they are asking you to resign. In my opinion, its too big a risk to take.

Comment: Why are you in a hurry to resign? I would assume that HR are expecting you to have a notice period, and the starting date should be accommodating that period. Maybe ask in an email explaining the fact that you need a written confirmation to resign and start your notice period.

Comment: What is a fitment letter?

Comment: @DavidK From https://findwords.info/term/fitment "(context India English) The categorisation of an employee, for the purpose of calculating salary or allowances"

Comment: @PeterM So if it tells you what your pay grade is, how is that different from an offer letter?

Comment: @DavidK I'm not Indian or work in India so I have no idea.  All I know is that they do things differently there.

Comment: It would be stupid to resign before you have a formal offer in writing (and on paper, not just an e-mail). Just tell HR that you will hand in your resignation as soon as you get the offer letter. If that takes a month, it's their fault, not yours.

Answer (score 10):

> They are promising orally that offer letter would be sent in a month

I can promise you over the phone that you will get rich, famous and own your own set of Yachts. (And there are business models build on doing just that for money). But should you believe that and resign because of that? Probably not.

I'm sure *they* only accept written statements (or would they accept phonecall from you telling them you have a relieving letter? No they won't, they want to see the thing).

So... it's up to you whether you trust them to follow up on their promises, but conventional wisdom says you do not resign from your old job, until you have the new job in writing. If they had no doubts and *really* wanted to hire you, you'd have a written job offer by now. Once you resign you are in a weaker position to negotiate and basically have to take the deal they offer you *then*. You need to negotiate that deal *now* while you are still in a position of power and have a job.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't sound good. To quote from a movie: tomorrow is a promise to no one.

Answer (score 2):

> Can I resign without offer letter and only fitment letter?

You can do whatever you want. I think the question you meant to ask is "Should I resign without offer letter and only fitment letter?" - To that, I would say no unless you're confident that you'll get the offer letter.

> Can they deny sending offer letter tomorrow?

They can do whatever they want. How confident are you that they will send you the offer letter?

Answer (score 0):

> They are promising orally that offer letter would be sent in a month

This is probably a red flag, although you need to get an opinion from someone who knows how things work in the part of the world where you are (India?).

But, it looks to me that if they really wanted to send you an offer letter, they would not need a month. There's no plausible reason why it cannot be sent in a few days or at most a week.

Claiming that they need a month... there's something fishy going on. Or else they're disorganized to the extreme, in which case you probably don't want to work for them anyway.

One possible reason (mind you, I'm just guessing here) is that in the new company, the local manager wants more workers, but has not got the higher management to approve it yet; he already started the process (that is, he had the local HR talk to you), and is hoping to get the approval eventually and then have you work immediately after.
Where such schemes fail is if the higher management in the end does not approve the request for more workers... and then the potential employee (you) finds himself without the old job, and without the new one also.

In places with working legal system, in such a situation, if you have received the job offer, you can then sue the company for cancelling it. I don't know if that would work in India or not... so it might be that having the job offer on paper does not give you as much protection there.

But in any case it's generally better to have it on paper. And a refusal to give you an offer on paper is a significant red flag.